Mouse keeps disconnecting randomly
I'm having problems with my SteelSeries Rival 3 gaming mouse after installing Arch Linux x86_64 with kernel 6.10.9-arch1-1.
On Ubunu, Linuxmint and Fedora my mouse worked perfectly fine.
It only disconnects for a few seconds and then reconnects.
I do remember when i used Windows and i plugged in my mouse it automatically installed some Steel Series proprietary software (Plug&Play) and maybe this is causing some issue?
This is the output from journalctl right after my mouse disconnects.
Sep 11 00:34:27 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Sep 11 00:34:27 Arch kernel: input: SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1038:184C.000F/input/input24
Sep 11 00:34:27 Arch kernel: hid-generic 0003:1038:184C.000F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 3] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
Sep 11 00:34:27 Arch kernel: input: SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 3 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:1038:184C.0010/input/input25
Sep 11 00:34:28 Arch kernel: hid-generic 0003:1038:184C.0010: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 3] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
Sep 11 00:34:28 Arch systemd-logind[670]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 3 Keyboard)
Sep 11 00:35:34 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:35:34 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:35:34 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:35:34 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:35:35 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Sep 11 00:35:35 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
Sep 11 00:35:35 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
Sep 11 00:35:35 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: device not accepting address 8, error -71  
Sep 11 00:35:35 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
Sep 11 00:35:36 Arch kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Sep 11 00:36:23 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:36:23 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:36:36 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 00:36:36 Arch rtkit-daemon[813]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.

What i already tried with no success

3.8.2 USB
autosuspend https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management

Remove ddcutil usb rules https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/ddcutil/-/merge_requests/1



From errno.h, error 71 is e EPROTO 71 /* Protocol error */  . I'd suspect a battery replacement might help.
